# How to create a .war file in gwt using maven in eclipse?

Tags: java, maven, gwt, war

I want to create a war of my GWTApp. According to many tutorials I would have create a package as follows -

```
 <package>war</package>
```

in `pom.xml`. But when I deploy the war on `tomcat` it show me 404 Error. The war does not contain any host page or dependency.

The following is my `pom.xml` file -

```
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>testing</groupId>
    <artifactId>testing</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

 <dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
   </dependency>
   </dependencies>
 </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
     <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
     <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
     <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-codeserver</artifactId>
     <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
  <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
   <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
       <excludes>
         <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
       </excludes>
     </resource>
   </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
<!--         <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> -->
       <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
<!--         <version>3.1</version> -->
        <configuration>
        <webXml>\mavenWorkspace\testing\war\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
        <source/>
        <target/>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

and war structure is like

```
war
   META-INF
    -maven
    -manifest
   WEB-INF
    -classes
    -lib
   -web.xml
```

and lib folder contain only `gwt-servlet.jar`.

Comment: How do you access web application (URL)? Can you post stack trace from application server?

Comment: i manually host this war on tomcat

Comment: HTTP Status 404 - /testing-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/

type Status report

message /testing-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/

description The requested resource (/testing-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/) is not available.

Apache Tomcat/6.0.24

Comment: When you deploy it on Tomcat - any error occurs during deployment?

Comment: Might be missing a `<warSourceDirectory>war</warSourceDirectory>` from the maven-war-plugin config. It defaults to `src/main/webapp'.

Comment: ok lets try but i give my web.xml path from local drive directly. so its may create any problem

Comment: i do this because i configure my gwt project to maven so no src/main create

Comment: yeah mam, now its create empty war folder ..

Comment: war file is created but nocache.js not found

Comment: this is faced because nocache.js not exist in war folder.....

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have the gwt-maven-plugin in your project. GWT requires a compile step, so try with adding that.

Comment: thanks for your response but actually I haven't so much idea of maven could you please tell me how can i use this step by step

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a proper example handy right now (mine is from gwt 2.3.0 and probably doesn't work anymore). I would recommend taking in a ready sample-project with GWT and comparing it with yours. Quick googling sent me to: https://github.com/steinsag/gwt-maven-example